# Refactoring ugly ruby code

Tags: ruby, refactoring

The code below gets some text, find commas, and returns an array of a split up version without the commas.

```
class A
  def separate_comma_values(text)
    txt_len = text.length
    if txt_len == 0
      return [""]
    end
    final = []
    sub_arry = ""

    for i in (0...txt_len)
      ch = text[i]
      if ch == ","
        final << sub_arry
        final << ""
        sub = ""
      else
        sub_arry += ch
      end
    end
    return final
  end
end
```

This is a sample input and output:

```
s = A.new
print s.separate_comma_values("dh,,,dhhd,jhb")
# => ["dh", "", "dh", "", "dh", "", "dhdhhd", ""]
```

Although it does what I want it to do, I feel that there is something just not right about it. It's just dirty.

I am aware that I can use a built in method provided by ruby to achieve the split.

**Edit:** I guess this was edit out of my original post. The motivation behind this was to apply the knowledge I found after reading a ruby book.

Comment: You could start by fixing the misaligned whitespace, which someone just did for you. Also don't abbreviate variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only proper way to refactor your code is, obviously, to use `String#split`.

Although, just for fun:

```
def separate_comma_values(text)
  text.each_char.reduce(['']) do |splitted, char|    
    if char == ','
      splitted << ''
    else
      splitted.last << char
    end    
    next splitted    
  end    
end
```

Comment: This looks cleaner than my original implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There's a method in Ruby that does what you want.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-split

```
2.0.0p0 :001 > "dh,,,dhhd,jhb".split(',')
 => ["dh", "", "", "dhhd", "jhb"]
```

So, your code might end up being as simple as

```
def separate_comma_values(text)
  text.split(',')
end
```

**Update**: Sorry, I missed the part where you mention you already know about `split`. Oops.

Comment: If OP's output is truly what he wants then `split` isn't what he's looking for anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little cleaner, although as @depa points out, if you're trying to split based on commas, there's an easier way, and your (and thus this) code doesn't work right.

```
class A
  def separate_comma_values(text)
    return [""] if text.empty?

    final = []
    sub_arry = ""

    text.each_char do |ch|
      if ch == ","
        final << sub_arry
        final << ""
      else
        sub_arry += ch
      end
    end

    return final
  end
end

s = A.new
print s.separate_comma_values("dh,,,dhhd,jhb")
puts
```

This outputs

```
["dh", "", "dh", "", "dh", "", "dhdhhd", ""]
```

just as your does.

Here's how I would implement your algorithm:

```
class A
  def separate_comma_values(text)
    return [""] if text.empty?

    array = []
    value = ""

    text.each_char do |c|
      if c == ","
        array << value
        value = ""
      else
        value += c
      end
    end

    array << value if !value.empty?

    array
  end
end

s = A.new
print s.separate_comma_values("dh,,,dhhd,jhb")
puts
```

This outputs

```
["dh", "", "", "dhhd", "jhb"]
```

Comment: your output is not matching with OP's extended output.

Comment: @RubyLovely, The first version is the same, the second version is correct.

Comment: Ok! Basically OP wants, `""` whenever `,,` will be found. Am I right?

Comment: @RubyLovely, Yes, it appears so.  An empty comma-separated field transformed to an empty string, just as `String.split` does.

Comment: humm while `split` does it,why such code needed? :(

Answer (score 0):

Just as a small trick for looking nicer (in my opinion), you should be able to skip the word 'return' at the end of the method, and your 'seperate_comma_values(text)' could be just 'seperate_comma_values text' without the parens (in your text editor, syntax color highlighting makes this not a problem of clarity at all)